# Header titles not showing up when using a modal?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to build an app that opens a modal when you press a certain tab bar icon, and navigates to other tabs otherwise. I've mostly achieved my desired effect, but I can't get the header titles to show up on the non-modal screens.

I've tried messing around with navigationOptions, stackNavigatorConfig, and the like, but nothing seems to work.

Here is a Snack containing my current code: https://snack.expo.io/@jonathanchaffer/modal_test

For reference, here is my App.js (imports excluded):

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeTab: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home",
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-home" : "md-home"}
          />
        )
      }
    },
    AddTab: {
      screen: () => <View />, // FIXME: Holding down the Add button causes it to navigate to an empty screen.
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Add",
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-add-circle" : "md-add-circle"}
          />
        )
      }
    },
    SettingsTab: {
      screen: SettingsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Settings",
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-settings" : "md-settings"}
          />
        )
      }
    }
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: "HomeTab",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      tabBarButtonComponent: TouchableOpacity,
      tabBarOnPress: data => {
        const { navigation, defaultHandler } = data;
        if (navigation.state.key === "AddTab") {
          navigation.navigate("ModalScreen");
        } else {
          defaultHandler(navigation.state.key);
        }
      }
    }
  }
);

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: {
      screen: TabNavigator
    },
    ModalScreen: {
      screen: AddScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Tabs",
    mode: "modal"
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

I would expect a header title to show up for all three tabs, "Home", "Add", and "Settings", but currently it only shows up for the modal, "Add".

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you include Home Screen and Settings Screen in the bottom tab navigator so when you define title for them, it only gives a title to the bottom menu. What you should do is, you should create a stack navigator for the home and settings screens with their title and then include those stack navigators inside the bottom navigator.

```
const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen,
      title:"Home Screen"
  }
}
);

const SettingsNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    SettingsScreen: { screen: SettingsScreen,
      title:"Settings Screen"
  }
}
);
```

Then you should do this in your bottom navigator :

```
HomeTab: {
      screen: HomeNavigator,
   ...
SettingsTab: {
  screen: SettingsNavigator,
   ...
```

Finally you should hide the header of the main stack navigator for bottom tab as otherwise there will be two headers for home and settings screen

```
Tabs: {
      screen: TabNavigator,
      navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
      header: null,
      })
    }
```

I tried this in your expo snack and it works. Hope it helps you.